# Error finding all image URL using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, css, web

I am trying to get the image links from for ex: "https://mangakatana.com/manga/damn-reincarnation.26360/c6" this website for learning python parsing!

##### My last code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://mangakatana.com/manga/damn-reincarnation.26360/c6"
img_urls = []

# Loop through the range of pages
for i in range(1, 54):
    # Make a request to the website
    response = requests.get(f'{url}/{i}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # Find the div tag with the id "page{i}"
    div_tag = soup.find("div", {"id": f"page{i}"})

    # Find all img tags within the div tag
    img_tags = div_tag.find_all("img")

    # Extract the URLs of the images
    img_urls += [img["src"] for img in img_tags]

# Print the URLs of the images
print(img_urls)
```

but it is showing error for `img_tags = div_tag.find_all("img")`

Comment: "showing error";  this means nothing if you don't share what actually is it

Comment: it doesn't find 'img' tag inside 'div' in this code . and I also wrote another code but it is showing '['about:blank']' not image link !

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through all the image tags and check if the webpage got special image attributes like "src" , "data-src" , "data-original", "data-lazy" or whatever you find there when you check the developer tools in your browser.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://mangakatana.com/manga/damn-reincarnation.26360/c6"
img_urls = []

for i in range(1, 54):
    response = requests.get(f'{url}/{i}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    img_tags = soup.find_all("img")

    for img in img_tags:
        img_url = img.get("src") or img.get("data-src") or img.get("data-original") or img.get("data-lazy")
        if img_url:
            img_urls.append(img_url)
print(img_urls)
```